# Revert to earlier version of Python in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio

Anyone know how to do this? I have Visual Studio 2013, which ships with Python 3.x. All of my controller projects are written in Python 2.7, and I would like to use VS to edit/create new python modules, and not have to manage two sets of code.

I'd like to remove Python and install 2.7 in Visual Studio if that's possible. The other option would be to update all the old Python code but that would be a huge effort.

Maybe another IDE would be the best answer...

Comment: it's not  as huge effort as you might think: https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html

Comment: That sounds like it's worth a try - thanks